# Configurar gitigore para ignorar carpeta pero no subcarpetas

Tags: git, gitignore

Tengo mi proyecto con una carpeta `"folder1"` que dentro de ella hay otra carpeta `"folder2"`, como puedo hacer para que `gitignore` ignore todo el contenido de folder1 pero no el contenido de la subcarpeta folder2

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo a la documentación

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore

usa el patron de NO exclusión que lo indica el signo de admiración (!), ejemplo:

ignore todo el contenido de `folder1` pero no el contenido de la subcarpeta `folder2`:

```
folder1/*
!folder1/folder2/
```

> Si el patrón comienza con `!` entonces es un patrón negado y emparejarlo
> significa que la ruta NO está excluida.

Comment: Hola, con tu respuesta he podido arreglar mi problema.
¡Muchas gracias, me ha servido de mucha ayuda! :)